# using property for django fields causes infinite loop

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to make fields in my model write once and read only there after. The solution I came up with is using the property decorators. Please tell me if there is a better solution, I'm new to django. I get into an infinite loop when I try to instantiate the model in the django shell.

```
class MapPointable(models.Model):
loc_latitude = models.FloatField(null = True)
loc_longtitude = models.FloatField(null = True)

@property
def loc_latitude(self):
    return self.loc_latitude

@loc_latitude.setter
def loc_latitude(self, value):
    if self.loc_latitude == None:
        self.loc_latitude = value
    else:
        raise ValueError("Read-only field, the value cannot be set")

@property
def loc_longtitude(self):
    return self.loc_longtitude

@loc_longtitude.setter
def loc_longtitude(self, value):
    if self.loc_longtitude == None:
        self.loc_longtitude = value
    else:
        raise ValueError("Read-only field, the value cannot be set")
```

Comment: @MMatt I want to set the fields when I create the object but the fields should not be modifiable there after

Answer (score 1):

your property's name is the same name as the model field. it should be:

```
@property
def loc_latitude_prop(self):
    return self.loc_latitude

@loc_latitude_prop.setter
def set_loc_latitude(self, value):
    #...
```

otherwise they start calling each other and you get stuck in infinite loop..

but I would not use properties in django, because django does not recognize these in ORM, it only knows django fields